# Copying jar's to a new folder using nsis

Tags: java, deployment, environment-variables, nsis

My setup created using the below script copies all the files it contains to a single folder, I want to create a folder `lib` in the `Calculator` folder and copy all jar files into lib folder so my application can find the jars that I've specified in the classpath. And how can I set environment variables using NSIS. Please help as I'm a new to NSIS.

```
; Name of our application
Name "Calculator"

; The file to write
OutFile "Calculatorv1.0_Setup.exe"

; Set the default Installation Directory
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\Calculator"

; Set the text which prompts the user to enter the installation directory
DirText "Please choose a directory to which you'd like to install this application."

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; *************************** SECTION FOR INSTALLING *******************************
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Section "" ; A "useful" name is not needed as we are not installing separate components

; Set output path to the installation directory. Also sets the working
; directory for shortcuts
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\

File G:\IMS\dist\Calculator.exe
File G:\IMS\dist\lib\*.jar

File a.nsi

WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe

; ///////////////// CREATE SHORT CUTS //////////////////////////////////////

CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\Calculator"


CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\Calculator\Run Calculator.lnk" "$SYSDIR\javaw.exe" "NSISExampleApplication1"


CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\Calculator\Uninstall Example Application 1.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

; ///////////////// END CREATING SHORTCUTS //////////////////////////////////

; //////// CREATE REGISTRY KEYS FOR ADD/REMOVE PROGRAMS IN CONTROL PANEL /////////

WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Calculator" "DisplayName"\
"Calculator (remove only)"

WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Calculator" "UninstallString" \
"$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

; //////////////////////// END CREATING REGISTRY KEYS ////////////////////////////

MessageBox MB_OK "Installation was successful."

SectionEnd

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; ************************** SECTION FOR UNINSTALLING ******************************
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Section "Uninstall"
; remove all the files and folders
Delete $INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe ; delete self
Delete $INSTDIR\Calculator.exe
Delete $INSTDIR\a.nsi

RMDir $INSTDIR

; now remove all the startmenu links
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\Calculator\Run Calculator.lnk"
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\Calculator\Uninstall Calculator.lnk"
RMDIR "$SMPROGRAMS\Calculator"

; Now delete registry keys
DeleteRegKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Calculator"
DeleteRegKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Calculator"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: If the app. is a desktop app. (with a GUI) then [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can 1) Put the jars in the right place. 2) Auto-update them as needed. 3) Set properties and environment variables. -- Why does a calculator require environment variables to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by adding the files recursively with the `/r` flag:

```
File /r "G:\IMS\dist\*"
```

This will preserve the directory structure, and the jars will be installed in a `lib` subdirectory.

Comment: Beware of a special behavior of the `/r` flag : if you give a pattern for getting the files (like `*.pl`) you can get other .pl files from the subdirectories of the `IMS` directory in this example. It is explained in the manual in some cryptic way.